# Mental blank! What am I missing with this oh so basic bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My brain has gone on holiday. I have a standard bootstrap install; what am I missing when trying to create this simple tooltip?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Hover over me</a>
```

Same issue on bootply: http://bootply.com/72237

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `options` is undefined.

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

And the tooltip is placed above the link so it;s almost not visible on bootply. Add `data-placement="bottom"` then it will be visible in the example.

Working example on bootply: http://bootply.com/72242